# css define size of div depending on space between above and below div (changes on higher resolutions)

Tags: html, css

I have a pop up which looks like the image attached below:

On smaller resolutions (smaller screen/ browser zoom in) the bottom buttons disappear. (see second screenshot)

How can set the css so the bottom part of the buttons always is shown and the middle part of the words will shrink according to the space it has?
(the "words" are a scrollable list so I don't mind if it shrinks)

[image]

On smaller resolutions (smaller screen/ browser zoom in) the bottom buttons disappear

[image]

Comment: if you can fix the resolution in terms of pixel then simply use media query... and hide/show the button accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```html
give header and footer a default padding, and give overflow scroll to middle content <div> 


    please convert this TailwindCSS code into normal css it will work

<div className="text-start">
  <div className="bg-white sticky top-0 z-50 px-6 py-4 border-b rounded-t-lg">
    <div className="rtl-dir text-start w-full">
      <h1 className="text-lg md:text-base font-semibold text-gray-900">
        put your title here
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div className="absolute top-4 end-4">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer rounded-full p-1 hover:bg-gray-200">
        <XIcon className="w-4 h-4"></XIcon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="relative">
    <div className="px-6 sm:flex sm:items-start overflow-y-auto screen-h-70 scrollbar--hide">
      <div className="w-full my-1">
        <div>add your scrollable content here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <DividerComponent />
    <div className="relative flex flex-col md:flex-row  justify-start md:justify-between items-start md:items-center lg:sticky bottom-0 z-0 px-6 py-4 text-end bg-white rounded-b-md">
      <div className="w-full md:w-auto flex">
        <Button>your button1</Button>
        <Button>your button2</Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The buttons will disappear normally because the modal(div) height is fixed
what i suggest is you use a relative height for the content inside you div
and to fix the problem temporary you can use

```
div {
overflow : auto 
}
```

this will give you a scroll whenever the height of element surpasses the div's height